# Please help identify this LEGO set with large black curved elements with orange stickers

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

Can you please help me identify this set.

[image: element photos]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are parts from [8058-1: Guardian of the Deep](https://brickset.com/sets/8058-1/Guardian-of-the-Deep)
[image]

except the [Black Aircraft Fuselage Curved Forward 6 x 10 Bottom with 3 Holes](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=87611&colorID=11&in=A).